# How to make an odd or even function?

Tags: python

Regardless of what number I put, It keeps telling me that `n` is an odd number...

```
def odd_or_even(n):
    if (n % 1) == 0:
        print('{} is an odd number'.format(n))
    else:
        print('{} is an even number'.format(n))

odd_or_even(2)
```

Comment: You mean `n % 2`. You will never have a remainder when dividing by 1.

Comment: modulo gives you the remainder, you are using 1, and one goes into `n` n times with 0 remainder regardless of the size of `n`. So it will always yield 0

Comment: You also have it backwards. When it `== 0` it's even.

Comment: You are confusing `n % 1` and `n & 1`.  The latter would do what you intended.

Comment: @FrankYellin That's true, but then you'd have to say != 0 for odd.

Comment: @JacksonTaylor.  Actually no.  For numbers in Python, zero is false and everything else is true.  The poster's original code would work just fine just by replacing `%` with `&`.  Of course, I agree with you that including `!= 0` makes the code more readable.

Comment: @FrankYellin, If they were to just change the `%` operator to a `&` then it would be swapped. If `n` were 3 then the statement would equate to `False` and it would print it is an even number. So if they would switch their print statements then you could remove the `!= 0`/`== 0` portion.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't realize that the code was incorrect in that way, too!  Thanks.  I was just noting that n%2 gives the same answer as n&1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `n % 2`, every number equals 0 in modulo 1, since for every `x` you have `x = 1*x + 0`.

Also the clauses are flipped (odd means that `x % 2 == 1`, while even means that `x % 2 == 0`)

Answer (score 1):

```
def odd_or_even(n):
    if (n % 2) == 0:
        print('{} is an even number'.format(n))
    else:
        print('{} is an odd number'.format(n))

odd_or_even(2)
```

(n % 1) is going to be 0 for any value n. If a number is even, the value of (n % 2) is 0 otherwise its 1.